# Generate custom sized images from certain images in media library

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

**How can I add custom sizes to images that are cropped and saved?**
Using the standard `wp add_image_size()` creates custom sizes for ***all*** images – but I want to limit, for example thumbnail-creation, to images that has been cropped with ACF Image Crop Add-on only.
I know of the "on the fly" alternative but it would be really nice to actually create custom sizes when you actually upload and crop images...leaving the original images alone...

Best, Niklas

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way you can achieve this as per 4.6.1 by using wordpress by default. You would need to modify the way wordpress core works or recreate a custom media uploader for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - thanks.
Strange to me that this behavior for wordpress isn't possible. There will be lots of unused images after a while. Especially now that WP started to use responsive images as well. I've checked the source code for ACF-crop plugin & maybe there is a way to create custom sizes there at the same time as making the cropping - outside of the WP core.